# Laravel attempt to read property on null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using simple `Gates` user permissions on my `Laravel`.

I have a permissions table with hasOne relationship:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
 public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserPermission::class);
    }
}
```

and in an `AuthServiceProvider` I have to register permission:

```
  public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Gate::define('is_admin', fn(User $user) => $user->permissions->is_admin);
        Gate::define('is_test_user', fn(User $user) => $user->permissions->is_test_user);

        //
    }
```

but when the record doesn't exist in my permission table then I have an error: `Attempt to read property "is_admin" on null`.

What's the best solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`optional` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-optional) is intended for this purpose.

```
optional($user->permissions)->is_admin
```

Comment: I'd note, though, that `hasOne` is not typically a good choice for permissions, as users will almost inevitably need more than one permission at some point. Consider using something like https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction instead.

Comment: I have 'a flat' structure. In the permissions table, I can create many columns.  So user will be able to have multiple permissions but one record in permissions table

Comment: You might want to add something like a `hasPermission($name)` function on the User model that handles the `optional()` logic within it. Will save you from writing `optional()` in dozens of places.